# transforming online from xml to xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF‐8"?>
<student>
<firstName>Faysal</firstName>
<lastName>Abshar</lastName>
<id>112233</id>
<plan>
<courses year="2">
<course>
<name> Database Management System </name>
<shortName>DBMS</shortName>
<record>
<grade>A+</grade>
<percentage>85</percentage>
<date>27-03-2017</date>
</record>
</course>
<course>
<name>Oracle</name>
<shortName>O</shortName>
</course>
</courses>
</plan>
</student>
```

I'm getting this error when converting it to xsl
SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Premature end of file.

Comment: Which tool are you using? I get an error only with the `libxslt` processor.

Comment: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.WPJJdWl950w ... this

Comment: Please edit your question and add your XSL stylesheet. Testing your input (unchanged) with a standard *identity transform* stylesheet  produces no error in that tool.

Comment: can you post the xsl code after transformation please :(

Comment: leave it ... its done thankyou for your precious time :)

Answer (score 1):

I am getting a different error, caused by the `"UTF‐8"` part in the opening XML declaration. The `‐` character is a HYPHEN (`&#2010;`). Replacing it with a HYPHEN-MINUS (`&#45;`) solves the problem.